# Django retain form data after GET request

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

How can I retain the data entered in a form with Class Based views?

```
class SearchView(FormMixin, ListView):
    # formview stuff

    form_class = SearchForm
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = 'spaces'
    # listview stuff
    def get_queryset(self):
            spaces = Space.objects.all()
            location = self.request.GET.get('location', '')
            radius = self.request.GET.get('radius', 2.0)
            space_size = self.request.GET.get('size')
            # chain all filters below
            if location and radius:
                    # create a geo POINT from location entry
                    geocoder = GoogleV3()
                    latlon = geocoder.geocode(location)
                    latilongi = latlon[1]
                    latitude, longitude = latilongi
                    current_point = geos.fromstr("POINT({0} {1})".format(longitude, latitude))
                    # get search radius from get request
                    distance_from_point = float(radius)
                    spaces = Space.objects.all()
                    spaces = spaces.filter(location__distance_lte=(current_point, measure.D(mi=distance_from_point)))
            if space_size:
                    spaces = spaces.filter(size__gte=space_size)

            if not spaces:
                    return None # return all objects if no radius or space.
            else:
                    return spaces

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = self.get_form()
            return context
```

Each get request is giving me an empty form, but what's the best way to leave the data in the form? It's a search page, so is a bit odd that it returns your results, but you can't see what your query was.

With a function view it would be easy to retain the form but I want to use CBV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_initial()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) should give you the initial data for the generated form:

```
def get_initial(self):
    return {
        'location': self.request.GET.get('location', ''),
        'radius': self.request.GET.get('radius', 2.0),
        'space_size': self.request.GET.get('size'),
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that seems like it ought to work but it's not returning anything. Even if I set those values to strings rather than try and get them from the request they still come up empty. Is it something to do with having the form in the context as well, that seems to be overriding form class + formmixin?

Comment: Right, it seems that it just had to be above the other methods, directly below context_object_name, not after the other methods. Thanks

Comment: That's weird, method order should not matter in Python. Isn't it possible you accidentally put it our of the class?